# The halacha-jewish-law tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

The [halacha-jewish-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha-jewish-law) tag is the most populated by far. It covers more than 400 of the questions, and could probably apply to at least another 400. It seems to me that in its current incarnation, it's so broad that it would never pass the "would anyone want to browse it?" standard I proposed [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119/how-many-mentions-warrant-a-tag/120#120). On the other hand, it is potentially useful as a way to divide the site broadly into Halachic and Aggadic types of questions.

Should we:

1. Leave it alone.
2. Try to add it to all Halachic questions, past and present.
3. Delete it.
4. Redefine it as only for questions *about* Halacha (e.g. history of, philosophy of, rules of, etc.) rather than *of* Halacha (e.g. Hilchot Shabbat, Hilchot Kashrut, etc.) and strip it from all specimens of the latter, past and present.
5. Redefine it only for future questions.
6. Other?

Comment: After much deliberation, I think that the browsing standard should not interact negatively with action #2. If there are 800 questions in a given category, so be it.

Comment: Now that I've added our [disclaimer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/48/cylor-disclaimer) to the wiki for this tag, so that it pops up when you mouse over it, I kinda like having this tag on all Halacha questions just for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think 6 ("other"), as follows:

I do think it's useful to have a tag for all questions of *halacha*: the problem is that there are too many. By splitting off subspecialties within the tag, we can be left with a generic tag for such *halacha* questions as don't fit any more specific tag. We already have one such specialty: [choshen-mishpat-civil-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/choshen-mishpat-civil-law). We can go through the [halacha-jewish-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha-jewish-law)-tagged questions to see which topics are especially prevalent. If we find, for example, that there are many *hilchos Shabas* questions, then remove [halacha-jewish-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha-jewish-law) and [shabbat-sabbath](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shabbat-sabbath) from those, tag them with a new [hilchot-shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hilchot-shabbat) tag instead, and mention the latter tag on the description page for the other two (and vice versa).

A tag for meta-*halacha* questions (history of, rules of, etc.) can be separate: [halachic-process](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halachic-process) or some such. Again, linking from one to the other.

The problem with all this is that it's easy to choose a tag without seeing the tags' info pages, so that people will mistag.

Comment: +1 I agree, but I think #2 above should also be incorporated for consistency's sake - retagging old questions that don't comply with the new system. As you alluded, we have a convenient breakdown provided for us by [Rav Ya'akov ben Asher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arba%27ah_Turim) . . . unless we think we can do better at categorization since we are not as constrained as he was. (E.g. _Tz'daka_ is not really _Yoreh De'ah_.)

Comment: Regarding the Shabbat example, do we really want to remove the Shabbat tag, meaning that we don't want halachic and aggadic Shabbat questions to be findable together?

Comment: @IsaacMoses: At least if the shabbat-sabbath tag gets bloated with questions.

Comment: I agree with the suggestion to subdivide and ask that if we do so we give them a common prefix (hilchut-kashrut, hilchut-shabbat, ... hilchut-other or some such).  It's really hard to browse the tags now because the structure (if any) isn't apparent to the newer user.  If we're going to retag things anyway, can we try to improve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be like (4) - but the exact opposite.
That is, since there are several different categories of questions (seperate from their *topics*) - e.g. halacha, aggada, history, Torah, Neviim, Gemara, "jewish life", etc - there should be a clear distinction.
There are those who are an expert in one category, but not in another - and there are those that are interested in learning about one but not the other.
(Originally there were several different proposals on Area51, one for each of the above... These were merged here, rightfully so, but there should still be some way to differentiate.)

Questions *about* halacha, as a subject and not the topic, should be marked accordingly (though I think that other than historical questions, meta-halacha questions would usually be halachic in nature, too... )

In addition, no. 2 is also a good idea - to apply the tag to historical questions - but not all at once, since that would cause them all to pop the top of the list and can drown any new questions...

Btw, while we're on it, the tag should be *renamed* to [halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha), with a synonym of [jewish-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jewish-law) (though I believe tags in general should avoid including "jewish" in them - its implicit - in this case it can cause confusion with a potential tag about [law]), and any other relevant synonym or translation.