# Should all [mourning-aveilus] questions be tagged [minhag-custom]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Should all [mourning-aveilus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mourning-aveilus) questions be cotagged [minhag-tradition-custom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minhag-tradition-custom) since the legal status of the vast majority of its rules is custom and not *halacha*? Is there a specific set of mourning questions that should rather bear [halacha-jewish-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha-jewish-law) for technical reasons?

Generally the set of rules is referred to as *nihugei aveilus* rather than *hilchos aveilus* for this reason.

Comment: Questions like this are why I think the value of [tag:halacha-jewish-law] is [questionable](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/121/the-halacha-jewish-law-tag) as it's currently used. The same could go for [tag:minhag-tradition-custom].

Comment: Minhag Yisroel Torah Hu.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned [elsewhere](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122), I don't think the [halacha-jewish-law](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha-jewish-law) tag should apply to all *halacha* questions: only to those that don't have a *halacha* tag of narrower scope. The same for the [minhag-tradition-custom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minhag-tradition-custom) tag: IMO it should apply not to all *minhag* questions but rather only to those that don't have a *minhag* tag of narrower scope. I think (though I'm willing to be convinced otherwise) [mourning-aveilus](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mourning-aveilus) is such a *minhag* tag of narrower scope.

Comment: (and @IsaacMoses's comment on the question) - So until that is figured out just let the tags fall where they may?